# Populating Data in Drop down based on another Column Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a small requirement where in i have a Text field named Employee Name and i want to Populate projects based on that Employee Name from other List. I have already populated the Employee Name but now i want to Populate Projects based on Employee Name.

**Requirement** : To Fetch Project Name based on Employee Name selection from other list and dynamically changing that Project Name Text field to a Dropdown.


How do i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does Project list has lookup of Employee Name?

Comment: No, So actually i am getting Employee name through Rest API and i want to get Project Names based on employees through REST API

Comment: I suggest you the list structure(list name, field names, fields types).

Comment: Sure LZ_MSFT.
List Name: Should Cost Projects.
Projects : The field from which we have to pick up data is Project_x0020_Name(Calculated Column).
Now as we have solved my problem earlier the employee names that i was getting in my previous solution based on that i want to filter the above project names. Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler(People Picker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").after("<select id='ProjectField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
    var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
        $.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
        $.each(employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results,function(j,item){
            if(employeeName==item.Title){
                $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
            }else{
                if(item.Title!=undefined){
                    $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
                }           
            }   
        });         
    });
    $("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    });
    $("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
        var projects=getAllProjects($(this).val());
        $("#ProjectField").html("<option value=''></option>");
        $.each(projects,function(i,project){
            $("#ProjectField").append("<option value='"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"'>"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"</option>");
        });
        $("#ProjectField option").each(function() {
            $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
        });
    }); 
    $("#ProjectField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Project Name']").val($(this).val());       
    });
})
function getAllEmployeeNames(){
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
function getAllProjects(employeeName){
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Project_x0020_Name,Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$filter=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT, is it possible to fetch project data based on project name?

Comment: Yes, using the similar method in the code above.

Comment: So , in order to populate Data based on Project, where will the function be lets say i want to populate the End Date for that project. Where do i write that code?
I am confused on that part

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT , could you just give an example as to how will i bring in a date of project on selection of project. If i see that i can work on it now.

Comment: Which list store the Project End Date and this list have a Project Name field?

Comment: the List that stores project end date is the list which is being mentioned in above code and yes this list has a project name field which is Project_x0020_Name.

Comment: I have replied in here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250648/populating-data-based-on-project-name/250663#250663