# Populating Data based on Project Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a small requirement where in i just need to populate Date Column Regarding that Project. The code below shows that i am populating the project name based on employee name.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
$("input[title^='Project Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Project Name']").after("<select id='ProjectField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
    $.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
    $.each(employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results,function(j,item){
        if(employeeName==item.Title){
            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
        }else{
            if(item.Title!=undefined){
                $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
            }           
        }   
    });         
});
$("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
});
$("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
    var projects=getAllProjects($(this).val());
    $("#ProjectField").html("<option value=''></option>");
    $.each(projects,function(i,project){
        $("#ProjectField").append("<option value='"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"'>"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"</option>");
    });
    $("#ProjectField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    });
}); 
$("#ProjectField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").val($(this).val());       
});
 })
 function getAllEmployeeNames(){
   var results;
    $.ajax({
     url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
    }
});
   return results;
  }
   function getAllProjects(employeeName){
      var results;
      $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Project_x0020_Name,Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$filter=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
    }
});
return results;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the end date column internal name is "End_x0020_Date", the following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").after("<select id='ProjectField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
    var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
        $.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
        $.each(employee.Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler.results,function(j,item){
            if(employeeName==item.Title){
                $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
            }else{
                if(item.Title!=undefined){
                    $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+item.Title+"'>"+item.Title+"</option>");
                }           
            }   
        });         
    });
    $("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    });
    $("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
        var projects=getAllProjects($(this).val());
        $("#ProjectField").html("<option value=''></option>");
        $.each(projects,function(i,project){
            $("#ProjectField").append("<option value='"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"' pdate='"+project.End_x0020_Date+"'>"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"</option>");
        });
        $("#ProjectField option").each(function() {
            $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
        });
    }); 
    $("#ProjectField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Project Name']").val($(this).val());
        var pDate=$(this).find("option:selected").attr("pdate");    
        $("input[title^='End Date']").val(moment(pDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
    });
})
function getAllEmployeeNames(){
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
function getAllProjects(employeeName){
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Project_x0020_Name,End_x0020_Date,Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$filter=Status eq 'Completed' and Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
</script>
```

[image]

If the End Date field is a text field, we need modify the code as below.

```
$("#ProjectField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").val($(this).val());
    var pDate=$(this).find("option:selected").attr("pdate");    
    $("input[title^='End Date']").val(pDate);
});
```

Comment: so if i want more columns like this, it is achievable through some changes. Lets just say i need a new field to be populated i can do that just as end date right?

Comment: hi, the projects name are not populated in this code

Comment: I am getting invalid date in my End Date Text Field.

Comment: Make sure the End Date internal is "End_x0020_Date", if the End Date is a text field, we don't need use moment library to convert it.

Comment: its working. Just one question how do i filter projects based on a field say Status eq Completed

Comment: We just add filter to the REST API, like $filter=Status eq 'Completed' .

Comment: in this code, where do i put the filter>

Comment: I have modified the code in the reply, check it.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Many questions coming up soon @LZ_MSFT

Comment: Hi Lz_MSFT, there is a problem i am facing with the code. It is not fetching all the names from the column. This column is being used in 2 different list views actually. I am getting only few names in the dropdown. Could you help me out on this?

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT. Is it possible to select multiple employees from the drop down and get the data based on that?